# SQL Alchemy - Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) not creating tables in test db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to build an API backend for my URL shortener. I have the database connected to the API as a dependency. For the CRUD operations, I am using the SQL Alchemy ORM.

The code for my main app works perfectly fine and performs all the major CRUD operations I have mapped through the API endpoints.

The problem arises when I try to override the DB dependency to use a test db instead of my production db for testing purposes.

There are no errors associated with this override, however, the test database does not contain any of the tables that would be created when `Base.metadata.creat_all(bind=engine)` is called.

When running the tests using **pytest**, it gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'testurldb.urls' doesn't exist")
```

The code for my tests:

```
engine = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{ip}:{port}/testurldb".format(
        user=user, password=password, ip=ip, port=port
    )
)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


def overrideDB():
    db = Session()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = overrideDB

client = TestClient(app)
```

The module where Base is instantiated:

```
engine = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://{root}:{password}@{ip}:{port}/urldb".format(
        root=root, password=password, ip=ip, port=port
    )
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
```

The table that extends Base:

```
class URL(Base):
    __tablename__ = "urls"

    short_url = Column(String(256), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    long_url = Column(String(256), nullable=False, unique=True)
    time = Column(String(256), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, short_url, long_url, time):
        self.short_url = short_url
        self.long_url = long_url
        self.time = time
```

There seems to be nothing wrong with the imports, so I don't understand why it's not creating the tables.

And second, it might be useful information that my main production db already has the Tables created.

Comment: The module where Base is initiated is where the the url to your production db is? A module is fully executed when imported. Perhaps don’t import Base from its “production location” but create a new Base in your test file?

Comment: @JarroVGIT the module does contain the URI to my production db. To the second part of your question: how would the new "Base" get the metadata about the tables from their class declarations? I would assume that the first instance of Base is what is used.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a module and import **all** models (not just `Base`, including your `URL` model)
2. After doing this, try to create the models again through `Base.metadata`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i hope it'll helps you

```
# db.py

Base = declarative_base()

async def init_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

And then

```
# main.py

@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    await init_db()
```

(read [FastAPI's Lifespan Events](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan-events) for info on `startup`)